# Accessing PHP variable value in Html

Tags: php, html

Hi I am noob in web development so I need help in a simple task. What I want to do is when user clicks on order id it will show all the parts with that order id and if user want to add something in it I want that user clicks on add part and the id of the order id to be passed to the page I want to call. But I am not able to access the value of the order id. Below is the code :

### code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Search.css">



       <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" id="logoImg"  height="100px" width:"600px">

          <div id="InputA">
                 <h1 id="h">Data Of Shop One</h1>

          </div>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(isset($_GET["data"]))
    {
        $data = $_GET["data"];
        $f=$data;
    }
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT O_no, piece_name,piece_code,piece_price,piece_qty,total,comments,shipped
        FROM parts Where O_no='$data'";

mysqli_select_db($conn,'shop1');
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo"
<div class='CSSTableGenerator' >
<table>
<tr>
<th>Order Number</a></th>
<th>Piece Name</th>
<th>Piece Code</th>
<th>Piece Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Comments</th>
<th> Shipped</th>

</tr>
";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))

{
    echo "<h2 style='text-align:left;float:left;'>Order nuber:". $row['O_no']."</h2>";
    echo "<h2 style='text-align:left;float:right;'>piece_name:". $row['piece_name']."</h2>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='Search.php?data=$row[O_no]' >".$row['O_no']."</a></td>";

    echo "<td>". $row['piece_name']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['piece_code']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['piece_price']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['piece_qty']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['total']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['comments']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='Yes' checked/>&nbsp". $row['shipped']."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";
echo"</div>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<input type=button onClick="parent.location='addpart.php?data='.<?php echo $data ?>" value="Add Part" id="btnOne">


</body>
</html>
```

Kindly suggest me a way to pass order id to the page I want to redirect. Thanks

### I Have solved the problem:

By changing:

```
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='addpart.php?data='.<?php echo $data ?>" value="Add Part" id="btnOne">
```

To:

```
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='addpart.php?data=<?php echo $data; ?>'" value="Add Part" id="btnOne">
```

Comment: Open generated html and see what's wrong. And btw - here `data='.<?php echo $data ?>` you don't need a dot.

Comment: @devpro what about mysql_error()??

Comment: Also please note that `mysqli_error()` require conn link as argument ( `mysqli_error( $conn )` )

Comment: when i click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: U r using both extension maybe typo error. Not related to question

Comment: @fusion3k i am not facing problem with the sql its working fine. I am facing problem in passing value to the other page.

Comment: Use `onClick="parent.location='addpart.php?data=<?php echo $data; ?>"'`

Comment: @Shaider Yeah, but when you will have a connection problem, you will obtain a blank page instead of sql error... What is the sense of catching error if the error is not caught?

Comment: @devpro can u suggest me a proper way to access the value

Comment: I hope u solved it? Bro

Comment: @devpro yes i have and i have edited the question with solution

Comment: This is my solution mere Bhai.. I suggest u this..

Comment: @devpro bro i have just seen yours suggested answer before that i made the changes but anyways thanks

Comment: Good work... Can I post it as answer than u can accept this. Otherwise people think question is still open?

Answer (score 1):

Really simple solution

```
$id = ID ARGUMENT TO GET THE ID
header("Location: page.php?id='$id'");
```

Now you have gone to a page with a parameter now make a call to grab it

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now compare in sql or whatever you use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM placeholder WHERE placeholder='$id'";
```

and there you go :)